Correcting the Alignment of Fibonacci Squares for a Proper Spiral Formation in R
I'm working on creating a Fibonacci spiral with squares in R. I have successfully generated the Fibonacci sequence and plotted squares, but the alignment isn't correct. The first square is not centered properly, causing issues with the spiral formation.
Here’s the R code I’ve used so far:
# Install ggplot2 if not already installed
install.packages("ggplot2")

# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# Define a function to generate Fibonacci numbers
fibonacci <- function(n) {
  fib_seq <- numeric(n)
  fib_seq[1] <- 1
  fib_seq[2] <- 1
  for (i in 3:n) {
    fib_seq[i] <- fib_seq[i-1] + fib_seq[i-2]
  }
  return(fib_seq)
}

# Generate the first 10 Fibonacci numbers
fib_seq <- fibonacci(10)

# Initialize the data frame
squares <- data.frame(x = numeric(10), y = numeric(10), size = fib_seq)

# Set the initial position
squares[1,] <- c(0, 0, fib_seq[1])
squares[2,] <- c(fib_seq[1], 0, fib_seq[2])

# Compute the coordinates for the rest of the squares
for (i in 3:10) {
  if (i %% 2 == 1) {
    # Odd index: Square goes above or below
    squares[i, "x"] <- squares[i-2, "x"]
    squares[i, "y"] <- squares[i-1, "y"] + squares[i-1, "size"]
  } else {
    # Even index: Square goes left or right
    squares[i, "x"] <- squares[i-1, "x"] + squares[i-1, "size"]
    squares[i, "y"] <- squares[i-2, "y"]
  }
}

# Plot the squares using ggplot2
ggplot(data = squares, aes(xmin = x, ymin = y, xmax = x + size, ymax = y + size)) +
  geom_rect(fill = "white", color = "black") + # Square boundaries
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) + # Maintain aspect ratio
  theme_void() # Remove axis labels and grid lines

The problem is that the placement of the first two squares is not centered, causing misalignment with the Fibonacci spiral. I need the squares to be positioned such that:

The first two squares are horizontally aligned.
The subsequent squares are placed below, to the right, above, and to the left in the Fibonacci sequence order.

How can I correct the positioning of these squares to ensure that they align properly with the spiral?
This image is my target!

How are you numbering these squares in the image? Are the first two the smallest? And you want them to be in the center if the image? If you look at content of squares, what is the desired output? How does it differ from what you have?

Yes, the first two are the smallest. I want them to be the start of the entire figure, and then the spiral would go as the figure. The figure is my desired output. My codes so far stuck at the position issue

I added two more directions to the code - and the arcs
# Define a function to generate Fibonacci numbers
fibonacci <- function(n) {
  fib_seq <- numeric(n)
  fib_seq[1] <- 1
  fib_seq[2] <- 1
  for (i in 3:n) {
    fib_seq[i] <- fib_seq[i-1] + fib_seq[i-2]
  }
  return(fib_seq)
}

# Generate the first 10 Fibonacci numbers
fib_seq <- fibonacci(10)

# Initialize the data frame
squares <- data.frame(x = numeric(10), y = numeric(10), size = fib_seq)

# Set the initial position and direction
x <- 0
y <- 0
direction <- 1 

for (i in 1:10) {
  if (direction == 1) {
    y <- y - ifelse(x == 0, 0, fib_seq[i])
    squares[i, "x"] <- x
    squares[i, "y"] <- y
  } else if (direction == 2) {
    x <- x + fib_seq[i-1]
    y <- y 
    squares[i, "x"] <- x
    squares[i, "y"] <- y
  } else if (direction == 3) {
    x <- x - fib_seq[i-2]
    y <- y + fib_seq[i-1]
    squares[i, "x"] <- x
    squares[i, "y"] <- y
  } else if (direction == 4) {
    x <- x - fib_seq[i]
    y <- y - fib_seq[i-2]
    squares[i, "x"] <- x
    squares[i, "y"] <- y
  }

  # Update the direction
  direction <- (direction %% 4) + 1
}

# Function to generate quarter circle arc data
quarter_circle_arc <- function(x, y, size, direction) {
  theta <- seq(0, pi/2, length.out = 100)
  if (direction == 1) {
    # Bottom-left arc
    data.frame(
      x = x + size * (1 - cos(theta)),
      y = y + size * (1 - sin(theta))
    )
  } else if (direction == 2) {
    # Bottom-right arc
    data.frame(
      x = x + size * ( sin(theta)-1) + size,
      y = y + size * (1-cos(theta))
    )
  } else if (direction == 3) {
    # Top-right arc
    data.frame(
      x = x + size * (cos(theta) - 1) + size,
      y = y + size * (sin(theta) - 1) + size
    )
  } else if (direction == 0) {
    # Top-left arc
    data.frame(
      x = x + size * (1- sin(theta)),
      y = y + size * (cos(theta)-1) + size
    )
  }
}

# Plot the squares and quarter circle arcs
ggplot() +
  # Plot squares
  geom_rect(data = squares, aes(xmin = x, ymin = y, xmax = x + size, ymax = y + size), 
        fill = "white", color = "black") +
  # Plot quarter circle arcs
  geom_path(data = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    quarter_circle_arc(squares$x[i], squares$y[i], squares$size[i], direction = (i %% 4) )
  })), 
  aes(x = x, y = y), color = "black") +
  #coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  theme_void() 


Thank you! Can you help to define the spiral as well? I stuck there as idk how to automatically define the quarter arc of circle to the desired point as center to particular square

certainly, I added the arcs to the code above

Nice! Thanks a lot. It helps!!
